# Python Check if windows is installed on a SSD or HDD

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I want to check in Python if Windows is installed on a SSD or HDD, I could'nt find anything helpful so i'm asking here. Thanks

Comment: Surprisingly I couldn't either, perhaps look into if it's possible with the `wmic` command and just parse it from python.

Comment: Check if TRIM is activated

Comment: How can i check if trim is activated?